# Finding names in txt file

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I have a long text in txt file (T1.txt).
I would like to find all the names (in English) in the txt file and the 2 preceding words and the 2 following words after the name.
For instance I have the following text:

```
    "Hello world!, my name is Mr. A.B. Morgan (in short) and it is nice to meet you."
Orange Silver paid 100$ for his gift.
I'll call Dina H. in two hours.
```

I would like to get the following dataframe:

```
   > df1
       Before         Name         After
  1   name is     A. B. Morgan  in short
  2               Orange Silver paid 100$
  3   I'll call   Dina H.       in two
```

Comment: This may need more details.  Do you have all names that start with initials, salutations or is there any other patterns in the name

Comment: Thanks @akrun, the names can be in any name convention. It means initials or not. I would like to support the both. They all start with capital letter.

Comment: It could be difficult if people have names like orange, silver etc..

Comment: @akrun, Even if they have name like orange the name will start with capital letter - Orange.

Comment: But also "Hello", "World" and "My" start with a capital letter in your example, so this condition might be necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: @R. Schifiniת Thanks. But the Hello is at the beginning of the sentence, while the names starts with capital letters in the middle of the sentence. I would like to find name which are usually 2 words or more that starts with capital letter in sequence.

Comment: Is there always a Mr. or Mrs. before the names?

Comment: @Iris, Not necessarily. Sometimes it can appear and sometime not. However, you can assume that a sequence of 2 words or more in the sentence are names. If they start with Mr., Mrs., etc I would like to omit these and take just the name itself.

Comment: Can you name with words the conditions for the selections of "names"? Because with only one example, we can just guess here...

Comment: @Avi Rather than list out and answer the clarification questions in the comments, it might be more helpful if you list out several instances of what types of examples would be expected and what type of examples would not be expected.

Comment: If you use the rule "any word with a capital letter and not in the first position of a sentence is a name", then you will not pick up names which are the first words of a sentence. I guess you would need a dictionary to filter normal words but a dictionary does not contain all possible variation of a word, but then again you could use the stem only. But what if a name also happens to be a real word? You would need to train a model to distinguish them...

Comment: @antoine, thanks a lot for your comment. My model is limited in the way you represented. However, If the name "Orange Silver has 100$" so there is a sequence of 2 words with capital letters at the beginning of the sentence and I can recognize them as name. Just single name words won't be supported by my model.

Comment: @Iris and JasonAizkalns I added 2 more examples. So I hope the vast majority of special cases are covered.

Comment: Additional point is that as indicated in sentence 3 - the name Dina H. is recognized since the word after Dina H. is 'in' not in capital letter so the dot is an indication of abbreviation of the last name and not an end of sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not perfect nor is it pretty, but it's a start:

```
text1 <- c("Hello world!, my name is Mr. A.B. Morgan (in short) and it is nice to meet you.")
text2 <- c("Orange Silver paid 100$ for his gift.")
text3 <- c("I'll call Dina H. in two hours.")

library(stringr)

find_names_and_BA <- function(x) {
  matches <- str_extract_all(str_sub(x, 2), "[A-Z]\\S+")[[1]]

  if (length(matches) < 2) { matches <- str_extract_all(x, "[A-Z]\\S+")[[1]] }
      name_match <- paste(matches, collapse = " ")
    beg_of_match <- str_locate(x, name_match)[1]
    end_of_match <- str_locate(x, name_match)[2]

     start_words <- str_extract_all(str_sub(x, , beg_of_match), "\\w+")[[1]]
       end_words <- str_extract_all(str_sub(x, end_of_match), "\\w+")[[1]]

          before <- paste(tail(start_words, 3)[1:2], collapse = " ")
           after <- paste(head(end_words, 3)[2:3], collapse = " ")
  return( data.frame(Before = before, Name = name_match, After = after) )
}

dplyr::bind_rows(find_names_and_BA(text1),
                 find_names_and_BA(text2),
                 find_names_and_BA(text3))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# 
#    Before            Name     After
#     (chr)           (chr)     (chr)
# 1 name is Mr. A.B. Morgan  in short
# 2    O NA   Orange Silver  paid 100
# 3 ll call         Dina H. two hours
```